# Unable to get taggable_friends in fb graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get my friends list, whom I can tag from my app I am building.

here is the url `me/taggable_friends`

Here is the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#10) To use taggable_friends on behalf of people who are not admins, developers and testers of your app, your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 10,
    "fbtrace_id": "BZ6EPL0H8BV"
  }
}
```

I have given user_friends permission and I have added testers for my app.
I am not sure what more to add? Some one please guide me

Edit: 
Here is the screenshot which do not display my entire access token
[image]

Comment: did you even open the link in the error message? it´s all in there, not sure what else to say, to be honest...

Comment: Dude, But i am just testing the app. How am I supposed to give the app for review without even writing the code, please be courteous enough to give an answer properly. What do you mean not sure, what else to say? Please don't say anything, if you don't know what to say @luschn

Comment: you have to finish the app before sending it to review. test it with someone with a role in the app. the error message is VERY clear. if it does not work with a tester, file a bug.

Comment: I am hesistant to file a bug, But I need to make sure that the process I am doing is correct or not. That is why asked here, but instead of helping me you are just beating me down. I am not a spam profile man, have some kindness towards beginners. Thanks

Comment: read my last comment again. there is no "beating down", i told you specifically what the problem is. we don´t even know what user you are trying with.

Comment: Then you could have asked me, what you are trying to do .. that would have been appropriate. I have followed the link, in the error. It just says about reviewing which does not give me any idea about how to fix the issue. I am using my account in which I created the access token.

Comment: and you could have included a lot more information in your question. anyway, that chitchat leads nowhere, there is one important question: are you trying with an account that actually has a role in the app? (admin, developer, tester).

Comment: I have added the screenshot, I am not doing it for any app, just the explorer .. but I have given access to user_friends in the permissions

Comment: try with your own app then, not with the api explorer app

Comment: hello 
first of all you need to open your app to public then submit to review so you can have this feature

Comment: No, I don't even know what code to write so I can submit to review. So I would request you to suggest me something, so I can use it in test mode/ prefrabbly in graph api explorer itself

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `application` dropdown at the top-right corner of the graph API explorer. Remember, you cannot test `/me/taggable_friends` if the dropdown is selected as "Graph Api Explorer". you need to select your own registered application in the dropdown list. (**Don't worry**. you don't need to write any code right now. you can start building your application after you finish testing. **BUT** you need a registered application id. It will take only 30 seconds, if you don't have any application listed [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) .)

Go to `My Apps` -> `Add a new app` -> enter details like name,email and category -> `submit`. Now you have an registered application.

Now head over to Graph Api Explorer, and select your newly created application from drop-down menu. Get user access token with `user_friends` permission selected. and finally submit GET request to `/me/taggable_friends`. You will see list of your friends whom you can tag.

[image]

Now the JSON response has all data that you can receive using this node. You can further narrow it down by using fields. Eg: `/me/taggable_friends?fields=first_name`. To see all available fields etc., please read documentation [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user-taggable-friend/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/user/taggable_friends).

Also see the `id` values in the response. This is not original user id. These are called [App-scoped User IDs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids). Another interesting field is `is_silhouette`. `"is_silhouette": false`, means the user has uploaded a profile picture. otherwise, `"is_silhouette": true`means the user has default profile picture. (default FB profile picture, silhouette of a male or female)

Hope this helps.